# compare two files and print matched string with one line above and one bellow

Tags: awk, grep

My File1 consist of ~100k entries and File2 ~100 entries. I want to look for matched string from File2 to File1 and print matched line along with one line above and bellow. For smaller files I used to do with the following commands. Now I need perform in on a large file and also I want all the 3 entries in one line. Is there a better way. I dont have much experience.

```
awk '{split($1, a, ":"); split(a[2], b, "-"); print b[1]" "b[2]}' File2.txt
grep -E "6263604 6263708|130370901 130370975" File1.txt -C 1
```

File1

```
10 . 6263344 6263490
10 . 6263604 6263708
10 . 6264818 6264947
3 . 383595 383629
3 . 384667 384714
3 . 386272 386392
6 . 130370427 130376400
6 . 130370901 130370975
6 . 130372394 130372488
2 . 114379141 114379596
2 . 114379141 114379738
2 . 114379141 114384667
2 . 114383186 114383306
2 . 114384055 114384148
2 . 114384055 114384667
2 . 114384407 114384617
2 . 114384458 114384667
```

File2

```
10:6263604-6263708
6:130370901-130370975
```

Expected Output

```
10 . 6263344 6263490 6263604 6263708 6264818 6264947
6 . 130370427 130376400 130370901 130370975 130372394 130372488
```

Comment: I notice in your code you don't include the `10` and the `6` in your matching criteria, only the range like `6263604 6263708` - what is the expected behavior when the same range exists for multiple first values or first values  that aren't present in file2, e.g. if `5 . 6263604 6263708` existed in file1 but `10 6263604 6263708` didn't, should the `5 ..` line from file1 be considered a match to the `10:...` line in file2 and so printed or not?

Comment: @EdMorton In this dataset the I checked with awk '{split($1, a, ":"); split(a[2], b, "-"); print b[1]" "b[2]}' File2.txt | awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1$2]=1; next}a[$3$4]{print $3, $4}' - File1.txt | sort| uniq -d and did not find such situation but yes there will be probability. My File1 is human gene region and file2 is drug target region; so the situation you are taking is possible for some other drugs. I am trying to do genetic modification upstream/ downstream of the drug target to see how it will effect the drug interaction. Thanks

Comment: All else aside, you can't create a unique value by concatenating 2 strings since `a bc` and `ab c` both become `abc` when concatenated. So `a[$1$2]` and `a[$3$4]` are wrong, they should be `a[$1,$2]` and `a[$3,$4]` or similar.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for sharing it. I generally used both the way. Honestly I was not aware of the difference. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[ .:-]+" }
{ curr = $2 " " $3 }
NR == FNR {
    a[$1 " . " curr]
    next
}
buf!="" { print buf, curr; buf="" }
$0 in a { buf=$1 " . " prev OFS curr }
{ prev = curr }
END { if (buf!="") print buf }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
10 . 6263344 6263490 6263604 6263708 6264818 6264947
6 . 130370427 130376400 130370901 130370975 130372394 130372488
```

Comment: this looks better, not matching the prefix bothered me.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk   'NR==FNR {a[$2" "$3]; next} 
               m {print $1,$2,pp,p,$3,$4; m=""} 
   $3 FS $4 in a {m=1} 
                 {pp=p; p=$3 FS $4}
             END {if(m) print $1,$2,pp,p}' FS='[:-]' file2 FS=' ' file1

10 . 6263344 6263490 6263604 6263708 6264818 6264947
6 . 130370427 130376400 130370901 130370975 130372394 130372488
```

assumes numbers are unique so there is no prefix match as in your sample script.

Comment: To be consistent with the question swap file no.s, e.g. `file2 FS=" " file1` (nicely done)